# to add extraction code to beautifulsoup loop

Tags: python, html, loops, beautifulsoup

I have a code that extracts 2 links from txt file for example

```
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagenconsulting/kommentare
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagennutzfahrzeuge/kommentare
```

Below code extracts from that links arbeitsatmosphare data and firma data (code works).

```
firma=[]

company=[]

arbeitsatmosphare = []

lineList2=[]

 with open((os.environ.get('mypath')+'/test.txt'), 'r') as file:

    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        lineList2.append(line.strip('\n'))

print(lineList2)


    for lurl in lineList2:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
        page = 1
        while True:
            print(f"Processing page {page}..")
            url = f'{lurl}/{page}'
            print(url)
            response = session.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            articles = soup.find_all('article')
            print("Number of articles: " + str(len(articles)))
            for article in articles:

                try:
                    arbeitsatmosphareText = article.find('span', text=re.compile(r'Arbeitsatmosphäre')).find_next(
                        'span').text.strip()
                    arbeitsatmosphare.append(arbeitsatmosphareText)
                except:
                    arbeitsatmosphare.append('N/A')

                try:
                    firmaText = article.find('div', text=re.compile(r'Firma')).find_next('div').text.strip()
                    firma.append(firmaText)
                except:
                    firma.append('N/A')
                companyText = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'company-name'})]
                company.append(companyText)

            page += 1
            pagination = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'paginationControl'})
            if not pagination:
                break

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Arbeitsatmosphäre': arbeitsatmosphare,
                       'firma':firma
                       'company': company

                       })

    print(df)
```

I need to include company information into output dataframe. For example "Volkswagen Nutzfahrzeuge". Company data is located in the page header below black stripe.

UPD I updated code, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (append company name in each iteration):

```
firma=[]
company=[]
arbeitsatmosphare = []

lineList2=[]

 with open((os.environ.get('mypath')+'/test.txt'), 'r') as file:

    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        lineList2.append(line.strip('\n'))

print(lineList2)


for lurl in lineList2:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
        page = 1
        while True:
            print(f"Processing page {page}..")
            url = f'{lurl}/{page}'
            print(url)
            response = session.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            articles = soup.find_all('article')
            print("Number of articles: " + str(len(articles)))
            for article in articles:

                try:
                    arbeitsatmosphareText = article.find('span', text=re.compile(r'Arbeitsatmosphäre')).find_next(
                        'span').text.strip()
                    arbeitsatmosphare.append(arbeitsatmosphareText)
                except:
                    arbeitsatmosphare.append('N/A')

                try:
                    firmaText = article.find('div', text=re.compile(r'Firma')).find_next('div').text.strip()
                    firma.append(firmaText)
                except:
                    firma.append('N/A')

            page += 1
            pagination = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'paginationControl'})
            company.extend([soup.find('span', {'class': 'company-name'}).text.strip()]*len(articles))
            if not pagination:
                break

df = pd.DataFrame({'Arbeitsatmosphäre': arbeitsatmosphare,
               'firma':firma,
               'company': company
               })

print(df)
```

Comment: could you please update all code? I tried you solution and have the same issue, maybe Im missing something

Comment: have the same error, that I had when used len(arbeitsatmosphare) method. ValueError: arrays must all be same length. Thats because it extracts 1 company per page, not per article.

Comment: @codecodecode You want it to extract 1 company per article or per page?

Comment: one company per url, but populated for all articles

Comment: same error, ValueError("arrays must all be same length")

Comment: @codecodecode What are the lengths of these three arrays? They have to be the same.

Comment: my code in main message extracts articles page by page, so firma and arbeitsatmosphare have same length. Probably company in your code count number of articles  on last page, so its not the same

Comment: @codecodecode Please see the code now; it's fixed - I tested it locally. This was happening because company data was added after the pagination check condition, so if there weren't any more pages left, the loop exited without adding company data.